# SmartFoxServer2x - Connection Issues

Tags: smartfoxserver

No one can connect to my smartfoxserver2x, neither LAN OR WAN (I tried to connect from 2 machines in my LAN).

I'm sure I've done post-installation steps properly; I have 9933 port open and forwarded to my machine and I have a Static IP.

Also, in the SFS2x's control panel -> server configuration I have added Socket Addresses of my machine's LAN Ip.

Through my public IP, anyone can see the SFS2x' default page, access the administration tools etc. but cannot connect to the server. It always says "Can't connect to server!".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the default 9933 port to something else, for example 3993, fixes the problem.